# Alexa Audioplayer M3U

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to build an Alexa Skill which streams an mp3 stream. But the Stream itself is http. 
But i had read, that it's possible to stream an http stream, if i create an M3U File which contains the stream-url, and host only this M3U File on my S3, to get an https url.

```
    var url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/radio.m3u";

    this.response.audioPlayerPlay('REPLACE_ALL', url, 'myMusic', null, 0);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
```

But it doesn't work. In cloudwatch log there is the following error:

> Player error occurred: com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.",
>               "type": "MEDIA_ERROR_INTERNAL_DEVICE_ERROR"
>           },
>           "token": "myMusic"
>       }

The MP3 Stream i wan't to use is e.g.
http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de:80/antenne

When i host an MP3 to my S3, and enter this url in my skill, it's working fine.
But even i enter this MP3-URL in my M3U file, and use the M3U-URL in my coding, it raises the same error.

Can someone give me an hint?

Kind Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

The [AudioPlayer Interface Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html) states:

> The audio file must be hosted at an Internet-accessible HTTPS endpoint. **HTTPS is required**, and the domain hosting the files must present a valid, trusted SSL certificate. Self-signed certificates cannot be used.

Your desired url is not HTTPS.

Comment: My URL is HTTPS.
https:// s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/radio.m3u

The Stream inside is not https. but thats okay. And not the reason of the problem. Even i have an https stream inside the M3U File, it's the same problem.

In the meantime, i found out that it's working, when i use M3U8 Files instead of M3U. No don't know the reason why M3U8 are working, but M3U are not working.

Comment: The URLs in the M3U8 files should be https also. If they are not - it won't work. So, that could still be the problem.